# Using Slick Carousal Plug-In

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to add [Slick's Lazy Loading Carousal](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) to a website.

**Tags**

```
<head>
    <link href="nav.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="home.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick-theme.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="slideShow">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slideShow').slick({
    lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
    slidesToShow: 5,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    infinite: false,
  });
});
```

I get two errors when the site loads saying that:

```
GET file://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
home.html:8 
GET file://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js    
net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

I am new to jQuery and I cannot figure out why it can't find the jQuery when using a jQuery CDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are accessing it locally, you have to add the `http:` within the script references.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

And:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. Maybe try:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```